# How to use Bhattacharyya as a kernel function in Matlab's built in SVM?

Tags: matlab, image-recognition, svm

I was wondering if there was a way to use the Bhattacharyya distance or kernel with SVM in Matlab?
I'm using the built-in SVM tool in Matlab and defining the Bhattacharyya as an external kernel function, but it seems like it can't be used this way (as in it's not a suitable kernel function).

Is there a known way to use it with SVM preferably in Matlab?

If not how can I find out more about how the default kernel functions work so that I can adjust the function to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, it has been done before apparently: http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/IMTC.2010.5488215. But not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus Yes I am aware it has be done before and that is why I am trying it. Although I might have to use a different implementation of SVM.